# TwitterBootstrap Group Inputbox and span in td tag

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have a table and for one of the columns i want each row in that column to contain an inputbox and beside the inputbox a badge with a plus sign in it. bellow is the code i have

```
<td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='email'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Email' value='{{this.attributes.email}}' title='{{this.attributes.email}}'>
    <span class="badge"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
</td>
```

howevere this creates an input box on one line and the badge icon is bellow the text box. i want the badge icon to be to the right of the text box. any ideas how to achieve this?

This is what the entire template looks like

```
  <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    {{#each headers}}
                    <th>{{this}}</th>
                    {{/each}}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each all_rows}}
                    {{#if this.attributes.isMaster}}
                    <tr data-row-type='final' style="background-color: green;">
                    {{else}}
                    <tr data-row-type='staged' style="background-color: grey;">
                    {{/if}}
                        <td data-parent='not-conflict'>
                            {{#if_eq this.attributes.isMaster false}}
                                <input type='checkbox'>
                            {{/if_eq}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='firstname'><input type='text' placeholder='First' value='{{this.attributes.firstname}}' title='{{this.attributes.firstname}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='lastname'><input type='text' placeholder='Last' value='{{this.attributes.lastname}}' title='{{this.attributes.lastname}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='businessname'><input type='text' placeholder='Buisines' value='{{this.attributes.businessname}}' title='{{this.attributes.businessname}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='email'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Email' value='{{this.attributes.email}}' title='{{this.attributes.email}}'>
                            {{#if_eq this.attributes.isMaster false}}
                                <span class="badge hover-add" data-funct="AddExtraField"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
                            {{/if_eq}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='address'><input type='text' placeholder='Address' value='{{this.attributes.address}}' title='{{this.attributes.address}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='country'><input type='text' placeholder='Country' value='{{this.attributes.country}}' title='{{this.attributes.country}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='phones'>
                        {{#each this.attributes.phones}}
                            <input type='text' value='{{this}}' title='{{this}}'>
                            {{#if_eq ../this.attributes.isMaster false}}
                                <span class="badge hover-add" data-funct="AddExtraField"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
                            {{/if_eq}}
                        {{else}}
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Phone' value=''>
                        {{/each}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='twitters'>
                        {{#each this.attributes.twitters}}
                            <input type='text' value='{{this}}' title='{{this}}'>
                            {{#if_eq ../this.attributes.isMaster false}}
                                <span class="badge hover-add" data-funct="AddExtraField"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
                            {{/if_eq}}
                        {{else}}
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Twitter' value=''>
                        {{/each}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='linkedin'><input type='text' placeholder='LinkedIn' value='{{this.attributes.linkedin}}' title='{{this.attributes.linkedin}}'></td>
                        <td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='urls'>
                        {{#each this.attributes.urls}}
                            <input type='text' value='{{this}}' title='{{this}}'>
                            {{#if_eq ../this.attributes.isMaster false}}
                                <span class="badge hover-add" data-funct="AddExtraField"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
                            {{/if_eq}}
                        {{else}}
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Url' value=''>
                        {{/each}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

From what i can tell it seems that the column is not making itself big enough to fit the input box and badge beside eachother. The only way i can get them on the same line is by nesting them inside a bootstrap gridding system but this just lays the 2 elements on top of each other.

```
<td data-rowis-yellow=false data-parent='email'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-6>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Email' value='{{this.attributes.email}}' title='{{this.attributes.email}}'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <span class="badge"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
        </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle, with your code, I've the span on right so...

Comment: Appears that what you have actually works, I've tested it against bootstrap 3.1.1 in my own project and also here http://jsfiddle.net/a82S7/.  What version of bootstrap are you using? Could you have some other css which is overriding the bootstrap style?